# How do I create a draggable UI element?

Tags: python, scripting

[image]

I want to add in my script a list of this type of element (can you drag), but I don't know how.

```
row = layout.row()
    row.prop/template_Id/?????()
```

Comment: Drag'n'Drop stuff is coded in C exclusively. Right-click that element, *Edit Source*: it will tell you that it's not python-scripted.

Comment: Thank, I hope for some changes in future, I wish to create some library of element (materials, objects, groups etc...) for easy access. A tweaks of Outliner.

Comment: I seem to remember that FluidDesigner has drag and drop.  Maybe this will help: https://github.com/Andyrexic/fluid-designer-scripts